# How can I get the element of another component in React.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have two components CarouselComponent and BannerComponent nested to App Component. 
I would liked to get the  element in BannerComponent in CarouselComponent for scrolling function.

Code is here;

--- App.js

```
....
<App>
   <BannerComponent />
   <CarouselComponent />
</App>
....
```

--- BannerComponent.js

```
...
return(
<div className="banner-div" id="banner-div">
</div>
);
...
```

--- CarouselComponent.js

```
...
scrollTo() {
  document.getElementById("banner-div") //  This doesn't work
}
...

return(
<a onClick={this.scrollTo}></a>
);
```

I wanna know how to get element in react js in all situations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`React ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) will work here.

```
class SomeComp extends React.Component{

constructor(){
    this.carRef = React.createRef(); //create ref
}
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <App>
          <BannerComponent  carRef={this.carRef}/> //pass ref in Banner Component to attach it to required DOM.
          <CarouselComponent carRef={this.carRef}/> //pass ref to CarouselComponent  to use it
        </App>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**BannerComponent**

```
class BannerComponent extends React.Component{

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="banner-div" id="banner-div"  ref={this.props.carRef}>
      </div>
    );
  }   
}
```

**CarouselComponent**

```
class CarouselComponent extends React.Component{

  scrollTo() {
    this.props.carRef.current.scrollTo(50)
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help. It works now.

Answer (score 4):

[forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) is what you need here to implement.

- First, set the ref in your BannerComponent component.
- Second, forward the ref in your App component.
- Third, get the forwarded ref in your CarouselComponent component.

---

Alternatively, if you still want to use dom, then I can think of possible way to do like this:

Inside App component:

```
state = {
  domMounted: false //initial state
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({domMounted: true})
}
```

This will ensure your full App component is mounted, now you can access the dom element inside your child component:

First, pass the props like `didMount={this.state.domMounted}`

```
<CarouselComponent didMount={this.state.domMounted}>
```

CarouselComponent component:

```
const {didMount} = this.props
if(didMount) { // this will run on every render and finally get true
  document.getElementById("banner-div")
}
```

Now, your onClick handler will not get null element and the event will work fine.