# Event in Child Component returns ' Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am actually new to React und when doing the tutorial of Lifting State Up , I have problems when I try to modify the value from the Child.js. It rejects an Error that  it is undefined. Second Question Why is it impossible to modify the Input value when the attribute is value and not defaultValue?.

Thanks in advance.

Parent.js

```
 import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Child from './child';

export default class Parent extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.change= this.change.bind(this)

        this.state={
            num:0
        }
    }

    onChangeValuebyChild(event){
       /* this.setState({
            num: document.getElementById('haha').value
        })*/

        this.setState({
            num: parseFloat(event.target.value)
        })
    }

    change(event){

        this.setState({
           num: event.target.value
       })
   }


   render(){
       const val= parseFloat(this.state.num)
       return (<div>
            <input defaultValue={val} onChange={(event)=>this.change(event)}/>
            {val}
            <Child numero={val} onChangeByParent={(e)=>this.change(e)}/>
            <Child  numero={val} onChangeByParent={this.change}/>
        </div>)
    }
}
```

Child.js

```
   import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Child extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.onHandlee=this.onHandle.bind(this)
        this.input=React.createRef()
    }


    onHandle(e){

        this.props.onChangeByParent(e.target.value)
    }

    render(){
        const val = parseFloat(this.props.numero);
        return(<div>
            <input
            id='haha' ref={this.input}
             defaultValue={val}
             onChange={(e)=> this.onHandle(e)}
             /> {val}
        </div>)
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a typo in your binding in the Child's constructor: `this.onHandlee=this.onHandle.bind(this)` you have `onHandlee` (that's not an answer to your question btw, just mentioning it)

Comment: recently answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51941434/how-can-i-get-the-element-of-another-component-in-react-js/51941499#51941499

Comment: I don't see the similarity

Comment: @Bayram Have solved your issue check the answer I posted, the issue was at the argument accepted at your parent callback function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved your issue in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/crystalthinker/c43hwdtj/

- You have a typo in the constructor at this.onHandlee=this.onHandle.bind(this); should be this.onHandle=this.onHandle.bind(this);

The error you are doing is at your parent you have :

```
change(event){

    this.setState({
       num: event.target.value
   })
 }
```

**this accepts an event and you are passing a value here from child.**

```
onHandle(e){
        this.props.onChangeByParent(e.target.value)
    }
```

**change this to**

```
onHandle(e){
        this.props.onChangeByParent(e)
    }
```

- When you assign value to input attribute it is like saying the current value of the input element. use state to change if you are using so:
  example: `<input type="text" value={this.state.inputVal} onChange={(e) => {this.setState({inputVal: e.target.value})}} />` , When you use defaultValue it is the initial value assigned to the input.

Answer (score 0):

You use onChangeByParent() as onChangeByParent(value)

so change your code to this code:

```
change(value){

    this.setState({
       num: value
   })
}
```