# React update a component from another in a nested element

Tags: reactjs

how can I update a component from another in react js?

I read a lot of post but i'm not able to find my case.

I have 3 react class:
Main class that contains my two react components:

`React Component A

React Component B

`

I would like to update the state of the component A using the component B.

**UPDATE 1/2**

I'm trying to follows the steps as you suggested but i have this problem:

i define a function in my main class:

```
handleArticleUpdate(codice){
alert(codice);
//this.setState({codice_articolo: codice});
}
```

And i'm trying to inject it in my component:

```
<MainGrid onArticleChanged={this.handleArticleUpdate} />
```

But i receive the error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleArticleUpdate' of undefined

I tryed to bind the this too but the error is the same..

MY CODE:

```
      import React, { Component, PureComponent } from 'react';
    import { NavLink } from 'reactstrap';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

    import {Form, TabPanel} from 'devextreme-react';
    import MainGrid from './components/MainGrid';

    import VisualizzatoreArticoli from './components/VisualizzatoreArticoli';
    import './App.css';

    const headerStyle ={
      border:'1px solid'
    }

    const contentStyle ={
      border: '1px solid'
    }

    const bodyStyle ={
      backgroundColor: '#999999'

}
//import { Loading } from '../../../theme- 
 sources/bootstrap4/components/loading';
  //import { CurrencyTypeProvider } from '../../../theme- 
  sources/bootstrap4/components/currency-type-provider';

    const URL = 'http://localhost:53139/api/randomData';

    //const URL = 'https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/data/orderItems';

    class App extends React.PureComponent {


     constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      itemsHeader : [
        {
          title : 'a',

          badge: 'New'
        },
        {
          title : 'b',
          text : "1",
        },
        {
          title : 'c',
        },
      ],
      itemsContent : [
        {
          title : 'Righe',

          badge: 'New'
        },
        {
          title : 'b',
          text : "1",
        },
        {
          title : 'c',
        },
      ],
      codice_articolo :''
    }

this.handleArticleUpdate = this.handleArticleUpdate.bind(this);

  }


getInitialState(){
  return this.state.codice_articolo
}

handleArticleUpdate(codice){
  alert("");
//this.setState({codice_articolo: codice});
}



  render() {


    return (
<div style={bodyStyle}>

  <div style={headerStyle}>

        <TabPanel
          height = '300'
          items  = {this.state.itemsHeader}
          itemComponent = {function(itemData){

              switch(itemData.title){
                case "a":
                  return null
                break;
                case "b":
                return null
              break;
                case "c":
                return null
                break;


              }    
            } 
          }
          >

      </TabPanel>
  </div>
<br />
  <div  style={contentStyle}>
  <TabPanel
    height = '700'
    items  = {this.state.itemsContent}
    itemComponent = {function(itemData){

        switch(itemData.title){
          case "Righe":
            return <MainGrid onArticleChanged={this.handleArticleUpdate()} />
          break;
          case "b":
          return null
        break;
          case "c":
          return null
          break;


        }    
      } 
    }
    >

</TabPanel>
  </div>








  </div>


    );
      }
      }

     export default App;
```

**UPDATE 2/2**

I think my problem is that my component is too nested (it's inside the component TabPanel) and handleArticleUpdate is not visible in the scope.

I tryed put only

```
 <MainGrid onArticleChanged={this.handleArticleUpdate} />
```

in the render() function and all worked perfectly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS Two components communicating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285923/reactjs-two-components-communicating)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the element of another component in React.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51941434/how-can-i-get-the-element-of-another-component-in-react-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Lifting state up

From the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

> Often, several components need to reflect the same changing data. We
>   recommend lifting the shared state up to their closest common
>   ancestor. Let’s see how this works in action.

In this case, it may be possible to move the state from component B to Main. This would be passed through the props to both components A and B, so that they both reflect the changes in state. If the state *needs* to be updated by component B, for example, from an onClick event, this can be done by passing a callback from Main to component B as shown already by Luke.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the methods inside the main component , and pass them down .

```
class mainClass extends React.Component {
  handleChangeOnA = () => {
     // ... LOGIC
  }
  render() {
      <ComponentA/>
      <ComponentB handleChangeOnA={this.handleChangeOnA}/>
  }
}
```

And then inside B, just call handleChangeOnA. Of course you'll also need to manage a state and pass them down as well . This process is called lifting the state up

Comment: i'm not able to inject the handleChangeOnA in the component b.. i receive the error Cannot read property 'handleArticleUpdate' of undefined

Comment: Where are you trying to activate it ? Can you share the code? I suspect you’re just missing binding

Comment: i'm tying to acrivate it in my main class render functiion

Comment: @Luke you need to update the question with your code

Comment: @Luke Looks like you're not binding your functions. Either add to the constructor this line: `this.onArticleChanged = this.onArticleChanged.bind(this)` or turn it into an arrow function .

Comment: I add it on my  constructor but i receive the same error. I updated the code